# Diff. b/w zip,gzip,gunzip,tar

Tags: unix

Kindly provide command line in UNIX to 
zip & uzip a file
gzip & uncompress gzip a file
tar & untar a file
kindly specify which is more suitable in best mode of compression .

Answer (score 3):

SO is not the manpage, so please look up the [complete](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar) [syntax](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?gzip+1) yourself.

Please note that tar is used to put multiple files (with a directory structure) into one file. It does not compress at all.
The usual compression in UNIX is gzip or one of its successors. Zip is seldom used. They are probably similar in compression ratio.

As a reference, here the most common commands:

Compress: `tar czf tarfile file1 file2 ...` (c: compress, z: use gzip, f: write to file)
Uncompress: `tar xzf tarfile` (x: extract, z: use gzip, f: read from file)

To use bzip2 instead of gzip use `j` instead of `z`.